# Manage multiple architectures using source-repositories dependencies in diskimage-builder

Tags: python, openstack

I haven't found references to the diskimage-builder in stackoverflow.

The `diskimage-builder` python package (`disk-image-create` executable) there is a possibility to install a dependencies based on:

- Packages: writing the package-installs.yaml file
- Source: writing the source-repository-my_element

The first options will take care of the architecture itself based on the operating system repositories, but the second option does not.

I wonder if there a possibility to manage different architectures for the source-repositories.

Here is the source code https://github.com/openstack/diskimage-builder
and documentation http://docs.openstack.org/developer/diskimage-builder

**UPDATE: current solution**

Looking at the source code of the element `source-repositories` I haven't found any usage of the $ARCH because the code is implemented int he extra-data.d phase, and no ARCH is passed there.

So, I have created multiple source-repository-my_element{, -i386}, one for the default (amd64) and another for the i386. For the example about compiling consul:

`source-repository-consul`

```
consul file /tmp/consul.zip https://dl.bintray.com/mitchellh/consul/0.5.2_linux_amd64.zip
```

`source-repository-consul-i386`

```
consul-i386 file /tmp/consul-i386.zip https://dl.bintray.com/mitchellh/consul/0.5.2_linux_386.zip
```

And then in the installation:

`install.d/10-consul-install`

```
if [ 'amd64' = "$ARCH" ] ; then
  # Package for 64bits
  PACKAGE="/tmp/consul.zip"
else
  PACKAGE="/tmp/consul-i386.zip"
fi

unzip $PACKAGE
mv consul /usr/local/bin
```